# Problema con CentOS 7: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

estoy intentando usar actualizaciones en mi maquina virtual con CentOS 7.7 pero al intentar utilizar yum me sale el error del titulo.

Las soluciones que he intentado y que han fallado son las siguientes:

- Configuración de yum.conf.
- Utilización de código "yum update --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base,updates" y despues utilizar yum update.
- Limpiar cache de yum.
- Cambiar la opción de dhclient con ONBOOT=no.

Si hay alguna solución que no conozca por favor poder escribirla como respuesta, ya llevo unas 12 horas en 2 días tratando de solucionar esto y no ocurre nada.

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Añado mensaje

```
    Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, langpacks
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    epel/x86_64/metalink                                                              |  51 kB  00:00:00     
     * base: ftp.inf.utfsm.cl
     * epel: mirror.cs.princeton.edu
     * extras: ftp.inf.utfsm.cl
     * updates: ftp.inf.utfsm.cl
    https://archive.cloudera.com/p/HDP/centos7/3.x/updates/3.1.5.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
    Intentando con otro espejo.


 One of the configured repositories failed (HDP-3.1-repo-52),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=HDP-3.1-repo-52 ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable HDP-3.1-repo-52
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=HDP-3.1-repo-52

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=HDP-3.1-repo-52.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from HDP-3.1-repo-52: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://archive.cloudera.com/p/HDP/centos7/3.x/updates/3.1.5.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
```

Comment: Parece un problema de conexion a internet, lo tienes todo bien configurado para acceder a internet? Prueba a hacer un ping a, p.e., www.google.es a ver si responde.

Comment: Si me hace ping a google al menos.

Comment: Podrias añadir el comando que ejecutas y la salida completa?

Comment: Ahi añadi la salida, solo ingreso yum update

Comment: El mensaje indica que no puede conectar al repositorio HDP-3.1-repo-52, ya que requiere autorizacion... has probado a ejecutar el yum desactivando este repositorio tal como te indica en el mensaje? (Ejecutando `yum --disablerepo=HDP-3.1-repo-52 ...`)

Comment: Si, pero cuando quiero volver a hacer un update normal o alguna instalacion  tambien tendria que agregar eso??? porque haciendolo una vez y despues un yum update no funciona.

Edito: lo probe ahora agregandole un update y aun asi no funciona

Comment: Para desactivarlo permanentemente tienes que ejecutar el otro comando que te propone el mensaje  `yum-config-manager --disable HDP-3.1-repo-52`

Comment: Sigue fallando aun con disable

Comment: Prueba a localizar el archivo del repositorio en `/etc/yum.repos.d/` y eliminarlo (o moverlo a otra ruta), despues de esto ejecutar `yum clean all` y volver a probar.

Comment: Lamentablemente sigue con el error

Comment: Pero continua dando el error sobre el repositorio HDP-3.1-repo-52? o es sobre otro repositorio? si es el mismo es que debe haber algun otro archivo .repo que lo configura, si es otro prueba a hacer lo mismo.